# ACF - Bootstrap carousel with thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields

i use for my website a slider bootstrap with thumbnails indicator.
I use Acf for wordpress to build my gallery

[Source Code](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/carousel-slider-thumbnails-25493000)

i display the slider and the thumbnails.
the slider works but nothing happend whaen i click on the thumbnails because i can't configurate the php code to set up the unique thumbnails ID and data-slide to

my code :

```
<?php $galerie_de_photo_images = get_field( 'galerie_de_photo' ); ?>
<?php if ( $galerie_de_photo_images ) :  ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div id="custCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" align="center">
       <?php foreach ( $galerie_de_photo_images as $galerie_de_photo_image ): ?>
           <div class="carousel-item">
             <img src="<?php echo $galerie_de_photo_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php the_field( 'nom_de_la_chambre' ); ?>  - <?php the_field( 'texte_alternatif_hotel_insolite', 'option' ); ?>" loading="lazy" />
           </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
        <?php foreach ( $galerie_de_photo_images as $galerie_de_photo_image ): ?>
           <li class="list-inline-item">
             <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#custCarousel"><img src="<?php echo $galerie_de_photo_image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php the_field( 'nom_de_la_chambre' ); ?>  - <?php the_field( 'texte_alternatif_hotel_insolite', 'option' ); ?>" loading="lazy" class="img-fluid" /></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

My JS

```
$('#custCarousel div.carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active');
$('#custCarousel ol.carousel-indicators li.list-inline-item:first-child').addClass('active');
$('#custCarousel ol.carousel-indicators li.list-inline-item:first-child a').addClass('select');
```

Comment: You can't have multiple ids of the same value, and data-slide-to should also be unique. Right now you have a value of zero - this value should increment to 1,2,3 etc - For this to be dynamic you should make a counter variable

Comment: i know. but i don't know how configure this with php @Stender

Comment: You can google "how to make a counter in PHP" - but  basically it is used like `$counter = 0;` and then inside your foreach you do `$counter++;` and then `echo $counter;` insted of `0`